# Acceptable proof of weak Nullstellensatz from strong Nullstellensatz

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was thinking of how to prove the weak Nullstellensatz from the strong Nullstellensatz, and I thought of the following argument. I am not sure whether this argument is correct in one of the two directions. To be specific, if $1 \in I$ where I is an ideal in a ring of polynomials over an algebraically closed field, since 1 can never vanish anywhere it's clear that $V(I) = \emptyset$. I have no doubt regarding this.

But, for the converse, if $V(I) = \emptyset$ would it be right to say that from the strong Nullstellensatz since 1 **trivially** vanishes on $\emptyset$, $1^k=1$ must lie in $I$. This just seems to be a play of words viewed from one perspective. Is this mathematically correct?

Comment: I've replaced \phi ($\phi$) with \emptyset ($\emptyset$) which renders better. To produce inline math, use single dollar signs enclosing your expression - double dollar signs enclosing your expression will force display-style. More information on how to use Mathjax on this website is available [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @KReiser Thank you. This looks much better.

Comment: I'm a bit late to this question. But notice that 1 is always a unit and if an ideal contain a unit then it is the whole ring $k[x_1,...x_n]$, $k$ algebraically closed. But then yes $V(k[x_1,...,x_n])=\emptyset$. So what you wrote is mathematically correct but I think you may need to prove the Nullstellensatz in it's full generality.